# Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: NSArrayM objectForKey

Tags: objective-c, ios

[image]

Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSArrayM objectForKey:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x12e654c0.

I am loading data on tableview from Array that has two dictionary objects. Dictionary object contains 2 nsstring object when ViewDidLoad called the code is below

```
while (sqlite3_step(statement) == SQLITE_ROW) {
    NSString* delID = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(const char *) sqlite3_column_text(statement, 0)];
    NSString* name =[NSString stringWithUTF8String:(const char *) sqlite3_column_text(statement, 1)]; 


    NSMutableDictionary *dict=[NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
    [dict setObject:delID forKey:@"delID"];
    [dict setObject:name forKey:@"name"];
    [self.arr addObject:dict];
```

It never crash for first row but on second row indexPath.row==1 it always crash please see the screen shot below. Thanks for help

Here is I am filling self.arr again
    -(void)popoverControllerDidDismissPopover:(UIPopoverController *)popoverController
    {
    if ([datePicker1.CurrentDate length]) {

```
UIButton *btn=(UIButton*)[self.view viewWithTag:btnTag];
[btn setTitle:datePicker1.CurrentDate forState:UIControlStateNormal];
}

if ([self.searchDel.arrSelectDelAdd count ]) 
{
    [self.arr addObject:self.searchDel.arrSelectDelAdd];



    [self.tblDelivery reloadData];

}

}
```

Comment: Because there is no dictionary data in second row.
what you are doing 
if (i==0)
    {
        [self.arr addObject:dict];
    }
it will add dictionary only if "i" value is "0">

Please check how many objects in your Array

Comment: Yeah I have can you see the screen shot above dict contains 1 object 

delID=002;
name="";

After crash I did print values in debugger

Comment: Please check you array length.
NSLog("Arrar  Count %d", array.count);

Comment: can u put the entire function??

Comment: Your `dict` is not an NSDictionary, it's an NSArray which *contains* a dictionary at index:0

Comment: Also, what is the idea behind `if(i==0)`? what *is* `i` in this case?

Comment: Simple thing is that after ViewDidLoad I am getting array count is 2 with the values in the above screen shot "po arr" and it works for first row fine but second row is crash

Comment: Show how u are adding the second dictionary object in the array..

Comment: @ctrahey the int i=0 for first time then I am adding what I get from sqlQuery to self.arr then rest of data to another array. first time my table shows 2 rows first row filled with data second row contains custom + button after clicking on custom + button popOver with tableview open after selecting any rows in popOver that's row data add to self.arr in dismisspopOver function then I reload tableview with self.arr that contains 2 object after crash I print the each object values you can see in the screen shot

Comment: @Mr.Anonymous When I called [self.tblView reloadData] getting arr count 2 and with the above values in the screen shot. "po arr"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry to bother all of you Actually the problem is that I am adding second or another object like

```
[self.arr addObject:self.searchDel.arrSelectDelAdd]; //Incorrect, that is adding NSArray type not dictionary
```

then getting values in cellForRowAtIndexPath

```
NSDictionary *dict=[arr objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];//here dict will contain NSSArray type not dict type object its causing to crash app.

cell.lblID.text=(NSString*)[dict objectForKey:@"delID"];// at this line.
cell.lblName.text=(NSString*)[dict objectForKey:@"name"];


[self.arr addObjectsFromArray:self.searchDel.arrSelectDelAdd]; // correct, thats the solution giving contents of NSSArray and now working my code
```

Answer (score 1):

Remove the if condition from your code. As it is just adding first dictionary into the array not the second one.

```
//if (i==0){
        [self.arr addObject:dict];
//}
```

Try this :)

Comment: Actually its serving another purpose After viewDidLoad I have 2 objects in Array. and that Return numberOfRowsinSection [arr count] that is 2